# forms auth or custom header auth for odata which is better

Tags: asp.net, security, odata

I need this up and running quick but I spent the last few hours researching/worrying about which would be better:

**Asp.net Forms Authentication**

vs

**Custom Header Token:**
On the server

```
protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.Get("magic")))
     {
           throw new DataServiceException(403, "Sorry No Magic found");
     }
      else
     {
           base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);
     }
}
```

On the **Windows Forms** client

```
static void datProvider_SendingRequest(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs e)
{
    e.RequestHeaders.Add("magic","HASHED_userbased_token");
}
```

Considerations:

- I've never used forms auth (but I can learn?)
- The user registration is complex (Employee records are checked then users are created based on those)
- I have my own custom usergroups/permission tables/system
- There is no SSL (client doesnt care about this fact, data is not all that valuable)
- I seem like Im more in control with the custom header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom header token. Forms auth assumes that a human will be authenticating to the service, which would be a pretty strange thing to happen on an OData end-point. OData is more about computers or services authenticating to the OData service.

Comment: thanks! =) Bonus points because your answer makes me happy! (I get to ditch forms AGAIN! =D)

Comment: FormsAuthentication, can be used to generate the magic token and instead of communicating through cookie, it can be made to validate from the header